# What is the default groupId for a maven artifact described as ":artifactId:version"?

Tags: maven, grails, grails-2.0

I just tried adding a grails plugin as:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-websocket:1.3.1"
```

which failed but the following succeeded:

```
compile ":spring-websocket:1.3.1"
```

why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The two are identical (or should be) as far as I am aware. Indeed I can add the following to my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-websocket:1.3.1"
```

And I see the following in my dependency report:

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:spring-websocket:1.3.1
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:4.1.5.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-websocket:4.1.5.RELEASE
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.3
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0
|         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.3
```

The grails documentation '[Plugin Dependencies](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.4/guide/single.html#pluginDependencies)' says:

> If you don't specify a group id the default plugin group id of org.grails.plugins is used.

I do not know why it did not work for you, but it should. I have checked all of this on Grails 2.5.4 but earlier versions of Grails 2 I believe operate in the same manner.